# Multiple definitions (versions) of a class without conflicts

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

So recently I came up with this idea to store some very common functions needed for PrestaShop modules in my own extended version of a class:

```
class MyModule extends Module { ...
```

There are lot of functions / common code lines / missing functionality that can be stored in an extended class. What I would like to do is to keep this class, add and refine it with the functionality that I need to speed up module development. So later I can just pop it in (the newest version of this class) and dramatically reduce the amount of code lines:

```
require_once('core/classes/MyModule.php');

class MyModuleName extends MyModule { ...
```

However, I also realized that I won't be able to do this if the application (PrestaShop) has two or more modules that use this class, because there will be a  class definition conflict. PrestaShop does have override functionality, but it is not an option, because if it detects a method that is already overriden, it throws an error (does not allow conflicts). We make a lot different modules, some of them we update, some of them we don't so we don't know how many of our modules the client PrestaShop system will have and which versions they will. Each module should be standalone, but should not conflict with other modules (if the exists and use the extended class).

```
PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class
```

1. Is there any way I can make this happen (using namespaces or something else)?
2. Is it bad practice to have multiple definitions of a class?
3. Would it affect performance by much ?

In `MyModule` case, I need to have access to Module object ($this) to define most of my extended functions.

I also would like to have `MyTools` class with static methods, but naturally it faces the same problem. Do you think that defining helper functions like this would be the way to go ? :

```
if(!function_exists(myFunctionName)){
   function myFunctionName(){
    }
}
```

Comment: At first glance this could be mitigated by using include_once and factoring the common code into a support/utils library that is shared as opposed to duplicated by both modules. Alternatively, namespaces is the way to go.

Comment: Yes but if put a namespace in MyModule.php class file, won't I have to prepend a global namespace slash \ to every other class used there? I may be wrong, I'm very familiar with using namespaces. I someone could give an example that would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best way to achieve this is to duplicate your class in every module you use, for this reason : your module have a dependency with an external class who will change in the time, so if you change something in your helper class for Module A, there will be no impact on Module B since Module B use its own helper. This is already how PrestaShop do with some modules to keep a compatibility between 1.4 and 1.5 version, with a backward_compatibility/ folder on each module.

Comment: Ok, ut how do you solve naming conflict? Append actualy module naem to each MyModule class -> MyModule{$moduleName} ?